# Why do I lose reputation points when voting down an answer or comment?

Tags: discussion

A few times I have read a comment or answer I regarded to be poorly written or considered. Subsequently I have lost reputation points. e.g. an answer within this: [Why don't users want to see adverts relating to products/services they might be interested in?](https://ux.stackexchange.com/questions/23247/why-dont-users-want-to-see-adverts-relating-to-products-services-they-might-be)

Is this right? I'd believe this is constructive feedback where I honestly believe the answer is poor. Isn't that why we can vote down? Or should I avoid this action?

Comment: Downvotes on questions remain free though

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Downvotes cost 1 reputation point so it stings a bit when you do it and you consequently think about which posts you want to downvote rather than just going around spamming the downvote button for every little thing you might not agree with. It's a good system. Don't avoid downvotes, just downvote sparingly and make sure you leave a comment explaining why you downvoted.

Comment: ok. got it. thanks